# Jackson JSON wrong format Spring MVC and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, spring-mvc

I'm just running into a very specific issue today:

I am working on a REST web service that is consumed by a Cordova Application via Ajax requests. Both apps are working like a charm, but, on the RESTful side services, Jackson is Mapping my POJO object twice, and I truly don't know why

Here is my Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search_machine", method=RequestMethod.GET,     produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody MachineSearch searchMachine(@RequestParam(value="longitude", required=true)double longitude, 
                                 @RequestParam(value="latitude", required=true)double latitude){
    return shopFacade.searchMachine(longitude, latitude); 
}
```

As you can see, I am returning a ***MachineSearch*** object, structured below:

```
public class MachineSearch {

    private String machineId; 
    private String machineName;
    public MachineSearch() {
    super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public String getMachineId() {
        return machineId;
    }
    public void setMachineId(String machineId) {
        this.machineId = machineId;
    }
    public String getMachineName() {
        return machineName;
    }
    public void setMachineName(String machineName) {
        this.machineName = machineName;
    }
}
```

My Ajax request here:

```
$.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        accept: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: host + "/shop/search_machine?latitude=" + latitude + "&longitude=" + longitude, 
        type: 'GET', 
        success: function(response){
            console.log("Success response: " + JSON.stringify(response)); 
            saveClosestMachine(response); 
            self.machineId(response.machineId);
            self.pageNumber(1); 
            self.gotMachine(true); 
            getMachineProducts(self);
        }, 
        error: function(request, status, error){
            console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request)); 
            console.log("Status: " + JSON.stringify(status)); 
            console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error)); 
        }
    });
```

The response body should look like this on my success callback

"{
        "machineName" : "Some value here", 
        "machineId" : "Some othger value here"
    }"

But error callback is being called with this console log

```
"Request: {
      "readyState":4, 
      "responseText":
           "{\"machineId\":\"c666ce3f-6ea2-4cad-b51a-55b6-8d49359b\",
             \"machineName\":\"Maquina 2\"}{\"machineId\":\"c666ce3f-6ea2-4cad-b51a- 55b68d49359b\",\"machineName\":\"Maquina 2\"}",
      "status":200,"
      statusText":"OK"}"
"Status: "parsererror""
"Error: {}"
```

Can anyone guide me through? As far as I know, I am doing everything straight up
Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand. Your content is in `responseText`. Why it's printed twice, I don't know. I also don't know why you're stringifying these values.

Comment: My problem here is that "success" function is not being called, or should I modify my ajax request to receive just text and my controller just return the json text?

Comment: Well, you have `"Status: "parsererror""`. You failed to parse something.

Comment: I know! I am trying to modify my ajax request, but, is still the same

Comment: Also noticing the same result from postman (web rest client), Something is wrong with my web conguration

Comment: I think your web app is fine. I think your client is broken.

Comment: What do you mean by broken? it does another requests using same ajax requests format and it does not give me that kind of problems

Comment: Misbehaving. You can see from the log that you got a 200, with the expected body. You can verify this as well by opening your browser's network console.

Comment: I just got it! It was just out of this context, I have a custom authentication basic filter on my spring security context; this filter was calling the filter chain, causing to "Redirect" my request, and appended it to the previous request